# Correlation between two groups with only one binary value

Tags: r, correlation, statistical-significance

I've got a dataset of entries that belong to groups A or B. Each row has only one variable, either 1 or 0, which stand for conversion rate. I need to calculate the correlation with a significance level between conversion rate between groups A and B.

Dataset:

```
   group conversion
   <chr>      <int>
1      A          0
2      A          1
3      B          0
4      A          0
...
```

I managed to get a value when running this command:

```
> cor(data[group=="A",][2], data[group=="B",][2])
            conversion
conversion -0.04052204
```

However, when I want to run the `cor.test`, I get an error for the same input values.

```
> cor.test(data[group=="A",][2], data[group=="B",][2])
Error in cor.test.default(data[group == "A", ][2], data[group == "B",  : 
  'x' must be a numeric vector
```

How do I go about doing this in R?

Comment: You need a point bi-serial correlation for categorical data: Check https://personality-project.org/r/psych/help/tetrachor.html